# HTML5 FileList and JQuery's each

Tags: javascript, jquery, file, html, each

I grab the filelist ([http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/#dfn-filelist]) and then I want to use JQuery's each function.

```
var file_list = $(this).attr('files');
/* Code goes here */
file_list.each(function()
{
/* Code goes here */
```

I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<FileList> has no method 'each'
```

Any idea? Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure your file_list is iterable? Can you explain your code more.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is because `$(this).attr('files');` just returns the plain DOM file list, and not a jQuery object.

Either you need to loop over it the old fashioned way:

```
for(var i=0,file;file=file_list[i];i++) {
 //do your thing
}
```

or you could use $.each:

```
$.each(file_list,function(idx,elm){
     //do your thing
});
```

Be aware that $.each is slower than the plain for loop, and in this case gives you very little convenience, so i'd stick with the for loop.

Comment: How do I get a JQuery object?

Comment: @thom: You don't - the filelist is not a DOM element but a javascript construct, jQuery cannot wrap it in a  meaningful way. It would be like trying to wrap a regExp object.

Comment: Is there a name for the `file=file_list[i]` style condition? I've always seen `i<file_list.length` instead and got confused by this syntax or what are its pros/cons.

Comment: I don't know a name for the construct, but it is a handy shortcut to get at each object if you have an array of objects you are traversing.  It works since the construct will return `undefined` when you try to access an index that is out of bounds, which will be coerced into `false`, and thus end the loop (objects are always coerced into `true`). On the other hand, you shouldn't use the construct if the array can hold values that will be coerced into false, like 0 or the empty string

Answer (score 1):

```
var file_list = $(this).attr('files');
$.each(file_list,function(i,item){
  // i is the index (integer) of current item
  // item is the current item
  // $(this) is the jQuery selector for the current item
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In 2011 May, jQuery 1.6 was released which changed the behavior of `.attr()`, you should use `.prop()` instead to access the `files` property of a file input.
Here are some additional ways to deal with a FileList object.

```
//Get the files property (FileList object) of a file input element from a jQuery instance.
var arraylike=$file_input.prop('files');
//Create an array from an arraylike object using the old hacky way
file_array=Array.prototype.splice.call(arraylike,0,0);
//Or the new way.
file_array=Array.from(arraylike);
//Or just work on it directly.
Array.prototype.forEach.call(arraylike,x=>{console.log(x);});
//Or if you really must use jQuery...
jQuery.each(arraylike,(k,v)=>{console.log(v);});
```

In case anyone wants to do their own research:

- [jQuery 1.6 release](https://blog.jquery.com/2011/05/03/jquery-16-released/)
- [$.fn.attr](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)
- [$.fn.prop](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)
- [$.each](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/)
- [Array.prototype.slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)
- [Array.from](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from)
- [Array.prototype.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)